# how to remote command in discord server using discord.py bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My friend does this using a node discord bot:

[image: remote command example]

I want to have a command in discord server using:

```
discord.py bot
!eval await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='test'))
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Have you looked at the [basic bot example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py)?  Could you share the code you have already written and explain how it is not working?

Comment: i want to code !eval await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='test'))

Comment: Do you want to make an `eval` command, or just a command that can change the bots presence?

Comment: eval command for in discord i want to type !eval code

Comment: look at this what my friend doing this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1v1s.png
his using nodej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from discord.ext import commands
import inspect

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='eval', pass_context=True)
async def eval_(ctx, *, command):
    res = eval(command)
    if inspect.isawaitable(res):
        await bot.say(await res)
    else:
        await bot.say(res)
```

Here's a basic implementation.  The `eval` function is doesn't seem to like `await` inside (I got syntax errors when I tried), so instead we can resolve a generator which we then `await` outside of the `eval`. You would call this like

```
!eval bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='test'))
```

Keep in mind that `eval` is *very* dangerous. If you expose this functionality to untrusted people, they can do whatever they want on your machine.  You should at least read [`eval` really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) to understand the risks before you proceed.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Errors are outputted to the terminal from which the python program was run.  if you want to do something else with them, you should implement an error handling coroutine [as described here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code and made it owner only.

```
@client.command(name='eval', pass_context=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def eval_(ctx, *, command):
    res = eval(command)
    if inspect.isawaitable(res):
        await ctx.send(await res)
    else:
        await ctx.send(res)
```